# How to run script on page from chrome extension context?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to know how I can be disabling the Event Listener "copy"

I think it's something like this:

.js file:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id === 'btn') {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, {
  capture: false
});
```

Thanks in advance!

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Just testing!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "48": "images/icon_48.png",
    "128": "images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon_16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the web page you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) because the popup is a separate page with its own DOM, `document`, `window`, URL, everything.

You also need to intercept the `copy` event as seen in devtools' event listeners panel:

[image: pic]

manifest.json should have the following:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["https://moller.jusbrasil.com.br/*"],
  "js": ["content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_start"
}]
```

content.js:

```
window.addEventListener('copy', e => e.stopImmediatePropagation(), true);
```

Let's break it down:

1. the content script runs at `document_start` before any page script
2. addEventListener's third parameter being `true` means our listener is invoked in the capturing phase of the event dispatch process - before any other standard bubbling phase listener
3. `window` is the first event target in the capturing phase
4. stopImmediatePropagation() is used because we need both to stop the subsequent bubbling of the event and prevent any other listeners attached by the page script from seeing the event

So the end result is that our listener is guaranteed to be invoked before the page listeners.

P.S. As you can see there's no need for the browser_action popup for this task.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. Just an explanation, google chrome disables the extension after I restart, what i do for don't to disable the extension? or would it be better to do userscript?

Comment: To use developer extension in Chrome you need to switch to Canary or use a fork of Chromium that doesn't disable such extensions (CentBrowser, for example, and some others). Using a userscript with `// @run-at document-start` is also a good option if you use Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey.